# .htaccess not redirecting me to correct place

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website which opens to `/resources/Installer/index.php`
but the path I need it to open to is `/Installer/index.php`.
I have asked my webhost to help but they have said they cannot help.

I have amended my `.htaccess` code to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and now I get an error message Error 404 - Not found
Your browser can't find the document corresponding to the URL you typed in.

The original `.htaccess` code was;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) resources/$1 [L]
```

My hosting structure is this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj6xV.jpg

Please see the `resources` directory,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9LNP.jpg

```
/
  /.opcache
  /Faucet
    /.local
    /config
    /controllers
    /functions
    /lib
    /models
    /resources
      /Installer
        functions.php
        index.php
        sql.txt
      /WolvenCore
      .htaccess
      index.php
    /storage
    /views
    .htaccess
    lib.zip
  /app897847581
  /logs
```

and the `.htaccess` file for `resources` is;

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There shouldn't be a problem with the code as it has been used before.

Comment: "I have a website which opens to..." - What do you mean by that exactly? Are you saying you are redirected (or internally rewritten) to `/resources/Installer/index.php`? "I have amended my .htaccess code to" - What was your original `.htaccess` file? Where is this `.htaccess` file located? What is your file structure? (It also seems a bit odd that you would need to modify `.htaccess` in order to run an _installer_?)

Comment: Hello, I have asked my web host for help as to why i cant access directly from the directory and they have said it is an issue with my htaccess, so i have looked into it and even they advised me to change it to there code, the code that was in the original file I have updated in the main post

Comment: And what's inside the `/resources` directory. We need to see a directory _tree_. That "original htaccess code" is assuming there is another `.htaccess` file in the `/resources` subdirectory. Please include the contents of this `.htaccess` file in your question. What is your document root? Presumably `/resources` is in the document root?

Comment: Hello,I have updated this now with the resources directory, and the tree, and also the htaccess file in resources.

Comment: I have included the file structure from your screenshots. If that is correct then your "original `.htaccess`" file looked correct IMO. You should be able to request `/Installer/index.php` and it will internally rewrite the request to `/resources/Installer/index.php`. Is that the intention? Does that not happen?

Comment: Yes that is the intention but it does not happen for some reason

Comment: I have raised this to web host to and they cant seem to fix it either, its a https sub domain if that would matter

Comment: Where does the "sub domain" point to in relation to the main domain? Are there any other `.htaccess` files along the file system path? Parent directories? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: its pointing at a folder inside the main directory and it is on same server as a wordpress site if that would matter,i have asked the web host and they will not let me change the override settings.

Comment: Is the "wordpress site" in the "main directory" (the main domain)? Effectively the parent directory of the subdomain's document root. `.htaccess` files work along the filesystem path, so the `.htaccess` file in the parent directory (even though it relates to a different host) can still apply here. Please include the contents of this `.htaccess` file in your question. (Although it can also depend on whether mod_rewrite inheritance is enabled - this may not be clear just by looking at the `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: Generally, if subdomains are not related to the main domain then they should point to filesystem locations outside of the main domain's document root - to avoid potential conflicts.

Comment: Yes the file system is outside of the main websites folders and I have tried my best to explain my issue I am sorry. the request in browser should be http://freefaucet.freegear.co.uk/Installer/index.php but it only works on http://freefaucet.freegear.co.uk/resources/Installer/index.php, Would you be able to have a look at this for me I would pay?

Comment: "Yes the file system is outside of the main websites folders" - not sure what you mean by that? Do you mean the WordPress installation on the main domain is in the parent directory (on the filesystem)? If so, we would need to see the corresponding `.htaccess` file - since that can also influence the subdomain (which is simply in a subdirectory off the main domain). However, the behaviour you are seeing is also as if `.htaccess` are not enabled at all? Type some nonsense at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the subdomain's root - do you get an error (you should)?